# Single acronym not being displayed in glossary

Tags: glossaries, abstract, acknowledgements

Bit of an odd one, I have a glossary that is printing out my glossary and acronyms using the command `\printglossaries`. This works fine mostly for every single acronym apart from one. The Acronym in question appears in the Acknowledgements which is created using the following:

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
     %Lots of text
     \acrfull{FX}
\end{abstract}
```

I'm having to do the renew as I've already create an abstract before. I was informed this was the best way to create an abstract and acknowledgments page in a `report` style document. The funny thing is that the acronym works fine here and is displayed correctly as I refer to it in the glossary. However, it doesn't appear in my glossary like my other acronyms do.

```
\newacronym{FX}{FX}{Long text here}
\newacronym{IDE}{IDE}{Integrated development envrionment}
```

On the creation of the PDF, IDE appears as it's elsewhere in the document, but FX doesn't as it's only being created in the acknowledgements. Is this a known feature? If so, is there any way to force the `\printglossaries`command to print that single entry?

One other thing to know is that the acknowledgment is on an unnumbered page. Could that also be affecting it?

[EDIT]
This is a minimum version that has the issue

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[acronym,section]{glossaries}
\newacronym{FX}{FX}{Some text}
\newacronym{IDE}{IDE}{Integrated development envrionment}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\printglossaries
\begin{abstract}
    Some blurb
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
    \acrfull{FX}
\end{abstract}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
    \section{This is a test}
    \acrfull{IDE}
\end{document}
```

[Edit] Added in Roman style page numbering

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[acronym,section]{glossaries}
\newacronym{FX}{FX}{Some text}
\newacronym{IDE}{IDE}{Integrated development envrionment}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\printglossaries
\begin{abstract}
    Some blurb
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
    \acrfull{FX}
\end{abstract}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
    \section{This is a test}
    \acrfull{IDE}
\end{document}
```

That causes the glossary to gain a page number, but neither of the abstracts do. I've tried using `\pagestyle{plain}` and `\pagenumbering{roman}` both before and after the `\begin{abstract}`, but both abstracts are printed without a page number

Comment: Please show us the minimal version of your document that has this issue. Do you have used `\newacronym` before or after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Added a minimal version, `\newacronym` is used before the `\begin{document}`

Comment: `\pagenumbering{gobble}` is the culprit!

Comment: OK, is there any method of getting around that? I'd prefer the abstract page stay unnumbered but I have referred to an Acronym there. Is it just easier that I manually input it and only change it if I refer to it again

Comment: At the moment I don't know why the `gobble` feature causes this. I'll check.

Comment: Apparently, `glossaries` does not print the item if the page number slot is empty. The easiest way to bypass this is replacing `\pagenumbering{gobble}` with `\pagestyle{empty}` for the abstracts and afterwards using `\pagestyle{plain}` (or whatever page style needed)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's `makeindex` that's rejecting the entry. The `makeindex` transcript for the provided MWE contains `2 entries accepted, 2 rejected`. The log (.alg) file contains `Illegal page number`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Hm, I missed that. Any solutions for this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not sure. The problem is that if there's no associated page number, the location list will have a blank element, which will look a bit weird. If the page number is merely hidden with `\pagestyle{empty}`, the location in the glossary will confuse the reader. For example, if it appears as `2`, then the reader will expect that to refer to page 2 of the main matter. It would be better to have `roman` numbering pages in the front matter with `\pagestyle{empty}` in the abstract. That should give the reader a better clue. Or just use a non-indexing command in the abstract.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: How about using a different entry counter? (Difficult, I know, since the abstracts aren't numbered)

Comment: That causes a separate problem, as I was looking at that. Because I have two abstracts, it removes the page numbering on the second abstract and I couldn't work out why. I'll update with the code I tried

Comment: Change that, it removes it on both abstracts, I can get a Roman numeral on the glossary, but not not on either of the abstracts and that causes the acronym to still not appear

Comment: You should do `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: How would that help getting a Roman numeral on the abstract pages? And where should I be doing that? If you're talking about after the abstract pages, I don't have an issue there.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't think a different counter would help. It wouldn't really mean anything to the reader looking at the location list. One possibility if the abstract must be on an empty page style is to set the encap to a command that will replace the page number with something more sensible. For example, `\acrfull[format=absloc]` and define `\newcommand*{\absloc}[1]{abstract}`.

Comment: That does appear to work, I've modified the `\newcommand*{\absloc}[1]{abstract}` to be `\newcommand*{\absloc}[1]{Acknowledgements}` and it now appears in my glossary. I think I'm also quite happy with the solution. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it for you? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I see. Strangely enough, you have the insight into `glossaries` ;-) I think, you should answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :-) okay, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarise the comments, the original problem (using `@gobble` as a page style) stems from `makeindex` not excepting a blank location. Using an empty page style to suppress the page numbering instead will satisfy `makeindex` but will confuse readers who try to look up the location's entry list since they might have trouble identifying the referenced page number.

Instead, we can make use of `makeindex`'s page encapsulation mechanism. This means providing a command that takes an argument, which is the location supplied by `makeindex` when it processes the source index files. With the normal `\index`, this encapsulation command is provided after the *encap* character (usually `|`) by supplying the command name without the initial backslash (for example, `\index{word|textbf}`). With the `glossaries` package, this is supplied in the value of the `format` key.

So we can provide a command that displays a word or phrase (such as the section title) that can be used as a reference in the location list. This command has to take an argument (the page number) but this argument can be discarded.

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[acronym,section]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{FX}{FX}{Some text}
\newacronym{IDE}{IDE}{Integrated development envrionment}

\newcommand*{\ackloc}[1]{Acknowledgements}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

\begin{abstract}
    Some blurb
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
    \acrfull[format=ackloc]{FX}
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
    \section{This is a test}
    \acrfull{IDE}
\end{document}
```

The result appears as follows:

[image: image of list of acronyms]